# How to split and concatenate strings in Perl?

Tags: perl, split

I was trying to split a path

```
Y:/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl
```

and I need everything except `Y:\` and then concatenate with another path

```
http:/aswee/5000/trunk
```

so that I get

```
http:/aswee/5000/trunk/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl
```

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: @new = split(/\//, $x);
  my $y = "http:/aswee/5000/trunk";
  $path = "$y $new[1] $new[2] $new[3] $new[4]";
     print FILE "$path\n";

Comment: As a side note, in case you need documentation on a specific function (in this case, `split`), you can use the `perldoc` command like this: `perldoc -f split`.

Comment: Generally, we like to see that you've made some kind of effort to solved the problem before we just give you the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using `split` it may be worth considering [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) - which is a platform independent approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $path     = 'Y:/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl';
my $add_this = 'http:/aswee/5000/trunk';

my ( $volume, $directories, $file ) = File::Spec->splitpath($path);

my $url = $add_this . $directories . $file;
print $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a 3rd parameter to the `split()` function in your example will make things much easier. Here's how you use it along with a couple of other ways:

```
my $path = 'Y:/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl';
my $url_prefix = 'http:/aswee/5000/trunk';

my $url;
# split into 2 parts and use the second part
my ($drive, $path_in_drive) = split(/\//, $path, 2);
$url = "$url_prefix/$path_in_drive";
# OR
# replace the part till the first / with the URL prefix
$url = ($path =~ s!^.*?/!$url_prefix/!r);
# OR
# extract the part from the third character
$url = $url_prefix . substr($path, 2);
```

Comment: This works fine....Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [spilt](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $path = 'Y:/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl';
my $otherPath = 'http:/aswee/5000/trunk';

#split in 2 part from ':' and use second one
my (undef, $splitted) = split(':', $path, 2);

print $otherPath . $splitted, "\n";
```

Output:

```
http:/aswee/5000/trunk/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl
```

Comment: I found out another approach                                                               my $path = "Y:/P18/4000/source/xyz.pl";                                    $url_prefix = "http:/asvn/cs_fcs_3000_4000/trunk";
 my $find = "Y:";
    $path =~ s/$find/$url_prefix/g;
 print  "$path\n";